# if single div, css apply on it if more than one, css apply on last one

Tags: css

Can we do something with single CSS property either from nth-child or last-child or anything else?

if only single child element, the color of that `child` should be red
`.child {color: red;}`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Hello</div>
</div>
```

---

and if more than one child element, the color of the `last child` should be red
`.child {color: red;}`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello</div>
  <div class="child">Hello</div>
</div>
```

---

**P.S.** - if single record is coming from API, then that single record should be in red color and if there are 3-4 records from API, then last records should be in red color.

Edited ---------------------

Thanks this is working for me one more question, what if we put css for pseudo element. Like:

`.container .child:before :last-child { content: "-"; }`

I got the solution -

`.container :last-child:before  { content: "-"; }`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: You mentioned last-child in your question. Did you try it? Did it not work?

Comment: Actually, I need if from api, there is only single record, then css should apply on that record and if more than one record coming from api, then that css apply only on last not first element.

Comment: who soever has put my question as negative, I bet him if can solve this. 
Actually, I need if from api, there is only single record, then css should apply on that record and if more than one record coming from api, then that css apply only on last not first element.

Comment: I'm not understanding the issue. If you have one element, then by default it's the first, last, and only when using last-child.

Comment: but how we can deal it with single css. I won't go with first-child or last-child - It will be restricted because if there are more than one record, I need that css to last element not to the first element.

Comment: That's exactly what last-child will do. One element only? last-child will select it. Multiple elements? last-child selects the last one only. See https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m4yvk7sd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the last-child property for that.

```
.container :last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This won't work - Actually, I need if from api, there is only single record, then css should apply on that record and if more than one record coming from api, then that css apply only on last not first element.

Comment: I think problem will be with how you attach the api data to DOM. I dont fully understand what you are trying to say but normally this should work. Can you please provide more details and perhaps more of your code.

Comment: P.S. - if single record is coming from API, then that single record should be in red color and if there are 3-4 records from API, then last records should be in red color.

Comment: last records meaning all records except the first?

Comment: it's the last record. mean the last one.

Comment: Why this solution doesn't work for you? Please take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/swuL17d8/

Comment: can you show how you are attaching the API data to your DOM. The problem will be over there.

Comment: thanks JithinAji @SeReGa